# Split strings before and after a word in R

Tags: r, string

I am using [Kaggle's 2017 Data Science Survey Data](https://www.kaggle.com/surveys/2017), and am  trying to look at
frequencies of majors. People have inputted double majors using the format, X and Y. (Engineering Physics and Medicine). Here is a glimpse of the data:

```
> dput(head(major_free, 20))
c("biochemistry", "architecture", "economics", "engineering physics and medicine", 
"chemistry", "software engineering", "image processing research area", 
"applied mathematics", "biochemistry", "mechatronic engineering", 
"sound technology", "major-graphic design; minor- asian studies", 
"english literature and langauge", "bioinformatics", "biotechnology", 
"electronics and communication engineering", "chemistry", "electronic with image processing and ai", 
"geology", "software engineer")

> head(major_free)
[1] "biochemistry"                    
[2] "architecture"                    
[3] "economics"                       
[4] "engineering physics and medicine"
[5] "chemistry"                       
[6] "software engineering"
```

I want to split up the double majors into two separate majors on two separate lines ( inside a data frame). I've tried:

```
strsplit(major_free, "and")
```

This gives me a long list, and I don't know how to turn it into a dataframe I can use to graph the frequencies of the majors.

2017/11/26 EDIT:

I wanted to do the same thing, but split before and after "&", ";", etc

```
> major_free <- unlist(strsplit(major_free, "&"))
Error in strsplit(major_free, "&") : non-character argument
> class("&")
[1] "character"
```

Weird that R is not reading it as a character in `strsplit`.

Comment: I've looked at this and it gives me two columns of majors with the newly formed column mostly NA. Is there a better way to do this and produce only one column?

Comment: Not posting this as an answer as you asked for an `R` solution. But this very simple `sed` on-liner would do the splitting job: `sed 's/ and /\n/' majors.txt`. If you have all your majors in a a file with one line each, that's all you need. There are issues with your data, however: I don't think you want to split *electronic with image processing and ai*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will take your basic `strsplit` parsing and the example data provided and give you a `data.frame` with a single column breaking out the double majors into two observations within a single column.

`data.frame(major = unlist(strsplit(major_free, " and ")))`

Though be warned that based solely on your example data, you will need to do more parsing as shown by row 13

```
data.frame(major = unlist(strsplit(major_free, " and ")))[13,]
[1] major-graphic design; minor- asian studies
```

And finally, if you do not want factors that you'll want to specific `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`

```
data.frame(major = unlist(strsplit(major_free, " and ")), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
li <- c("a", "a and b", "b", "b and c")
df <- stringr::str_split_fixed(li, " and ", 2)
```

Depending on the data, you could add somthing like `df[complete.cases(df), ]`
Please add a reproducible example, if this does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Or this, (only difference from answer by @Christoph is use of base strsplit function):

```
 li <- c("a", "a and b", "b", "b and c")
 data.frame(majors = unlist(lapply(li, strsplit, " and " )))
```

Comment: But structure is quite different from my `df`? Can you really reproduce stringr result (2 columns, not a flattened structure from unlist) with a few lines of basic R-code? This would be really great! The best I achieve is `data.frame(lapply(li, strsplit, " and " ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`